# How to use train in neural networks for Matlab R2009b

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network

I have input matrix as:

```
input = 
    1     0     0     1     1
    1     0     0     0     1
    1     0     0     0     1
    1     0     0     0     1
    0     0     1     0     0
    0     1     1     1     0
    0     1     1     1     0
```

and

```
T = [eye(10) eye(10) eye(10) eye(10)];
```

The neural network that I created is:

```
net = newff(input,T,[35], {'logsig'})
%net.performFcn = 'sse';
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 1; % training set [%]
net.divideParam.valRatio   = 0; % validation set [%]
net.divideParam.testRatio  = 0; % test set [%]
net.trainParam.goal = 0.001;
```

It works fine till now, but when i use train function the problem arises

```
[net tr] = train(net,input,T);
```

and the following error show up in matlab window:

```
??? Error using ==> network.train at 145
Targets are incorrectly sized for network.
Matrix must have 5 columns.

Error in ==> test at 103
[net tr] = train(net,input,T);
```

I've also tried the `input'` and `T'` as well. Any help is appreciated in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at MATLAB's official documentaion of [`train`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/train.html), you'll notice that `T` must have the same amount of columns as the input matrix, which is 5 in your case. Instead, try:

```
T = ones(size(input, 1));
```

or

```
T = [1, size(input, 1) - 1];
```

and see if this works.

Comment: i've one more question, how can now I test and extract result during testing

Comment: i mean taking the same example with matrix as input to the network how can i classify and test in generic

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can use [`sim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/sim.html) to simulate its behavior and obtain the output.

Comment: shall i take different T for different characters while training or T will remain same. say for example i have to recognize only first 5 characters of English. if my target is 5x5 diagonal matrix i would get 5x5 matriz in result of sim() method. How would i classify my character.

Comment: `T` is the desired output of the neural network for a given input, so you'll have to feed the network with different `T`s if you're planning on training it with different inputs.

Comment: Well, that really depends on the nature of your neural network... if you want the network to detect 5 different letters, you'll have to: 1) compute the desired output for your network for each letter, 2) prepare inputs for each letter (for training), and 3) train the network with the inputs of each letter, and for each input feed the network with the corresponding matrix `T`.

Comment: here is what i am doing kindly check it and tell whats wrong with it http://justpaste.it/1ib8

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/character-recognition.html) from MATLAB's official website. It is very comprehensive and might be very helpful for you.

Comment: thanks but if you could kindly guide me in the link for my code. What actually am I doing wrong. Plz

Comment: I don't have access to MATLAB at the moment, so unfortunately I won't be able to help you right now.

Comment: ok fine. Anyhow thanks for the suggestion of the matlab link :)

Comment: I'm looking at your code just to see if I can find any obvious mistake, but the problem is that your code is not indented, so it is very difficult to understand it. Can you fix the indentation and nesting?